# How to sort an arraylist with different data type in java

Tags: java

I have an arraylist which contains next data : name of an object and some details about him ( let's take as example a book and his price ). So we would have :

1. Book_Nr1_Name     5
2. Book_Nr2_Name     8
3. Book_Nr3_Name     4

> Where numbers 5,8,4 represents price of each book. How can i sort this array descending by the price , and get the final output like this :

1. Book_Nr2_Name  8
2. Book_Nr1_Name 5
3. Book_Nr3_Name 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an object Book to represent the name and price. Then create a collection of all books. Then we sort by the price using a Comparator that compares Integer values. We then collect to a List since it's sorted.

```java
  static class Book {

        private final String name;

        private final int price;

        Book(String name, int price) {
            this.name = name;
            this.price = price;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public int getPrice() {
            return price;
        }
    }
```

```java
        List<Book> books = Arrays.asList(
                new Book("Book_Nr1_Name", 5),
                new Book("Book_Nr2_Name", 8),
                new Book("Book_Nr3_Name", 4));

        List<Book> sortedByPrice = books.stream()
                .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(Book::getPrice).reversed())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Haven't used JDK14 yet, sorry. Good on you for using it though.

Comment: Ah, I thought you were OP, my bad. That being said, kind of irrelevant since OP didn't ask for JDK14 solution. Could have used Lombok as well but no point. Might as well KISS.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
Collections.sort(al, (ob1,ob2)-> -ob1.getPrice().compareTo(ob2.getPrice()))
```